# 2014 theme blog content area width

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

In WP theme "2014" blog content area (where ribbon of blog posts located) width seems about 50% of overall content space between left and right columns.

Which CSS tag corrresponds to blog content area width?

Comment: You can check that with the developer tool, in your browser.

Comment: There is no width attribute in style trace (Google Chrome development console; when pointing to blog content area).

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found that .hentry tag corresponds to post content area